# Page Reference not redirecting properly

Tags: visualforce

After clicking "clone" button page redirection isnt working properly.whats the root cause.Please check the below code .

client side:

```
function dateselect() {
    var startDate=$j("#date").val();
    alert('ds============>'+startDate);
    setdate(startDate);

    //var aid= "{!JSENCODE(cloneOppId)}"
    // var aid=('{!cloneOppId}');
    //alert('aid value===========>'+aid);
    return false;
}

function fun(true) {
    alert('iam calling=======>'+val);
}             
</script>

 <apex:form id="f"  html-novalidate="true" >
  <apex:actionFunction name="setdate" action="{!CloneSQ}" reRender="attendeepanel"  oncomplete="fun(true);">>
          <apex:param name="dateValue" assignTo="{!startDate}"  value="" />
    </apex:actionFunction>
  <apex:commandButton value="Clone" id="cloneButton" styleClass="slds-button slds-button--neutral" onclick="dateselect();">
```

---

server side:

```
public PageReference CloneSQ(){
    system.debug('<===============cloneSq calling======================>');
    System.debug(' esdDate========='+startDate);
    System.debug('AA:' + oSQ.Customer__c);
    cloneAccountId = oSQ.Customer__c;
    esdDate =  date.parse(startDate);     
    System.debug('AA cloneAccountId :' + cloneAccountId );
    cloneUser = pUsers;
    Id sqId = oSQ.Id;   
    Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
    string fieldsNames='';   

    //string newsqId;
    //cc = new Clone();

    if(cloneAccountId != null && cloneUser != null) {

        try{
            //Id newOppId = 
            CreateNewOpportunity();   
            //system.debug('opp= id '+newOppId);
            if(newOpp.Id!=null){
            cloneOppId = newOpp.Id;
            }
            system.debug('OpportunityId value ==========>'+cloneOppId);

            Boolean isInSameHerarchy = TeknionUtility.isAccountInSameHierarchy(sourceAccount, cloneAccountId);
            Boolean isTemplateAccount = TeknionUtility.isTemplateAccount(sourceAccount);

            System.debug('isTemplateAccount:' + isTemplateAccount );
            //Check if chosen account is same as source             
            if(sourceAccount == cloneAccountId || isInSameHerarchy || isTemplateAccount)
            {          
                //newsqId = startsClone(sqId,objLabelobjAPI.values());  
                CreateNewDealsheet(cloneDealsheetUserInfo,sqId,true); 
            }           
            else
            {
                //Chosen account is not same as source account
                //Read fields to copy from config
                CreateNewDealsheet(cloneDealsheetUserInfo,sqId,false); 
            }           


            //PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(hostURL + newsqId);
            PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/one/one.app#/sObject/'+cloneOppId);
            pageRef.setRedirect(true);
            return pageRef;


        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.Debug('Error at TeknionUtility.CloneDealSheet : ' + ex);
            throw new TeknionException(ex);

            Database.rollback(sp);
            return null;
        }             

    }
    return null;
}
```

=======================================================

opportunity creation Logic

```
  public  PageReference CreateNewOpportunity()
{

    newOpp = new Opportunity();
    newOpp.Name = pOpportunity;
    newOpp.AccountId = cloneAccountId;
    newOpp.StageName = oppStage;
    newOpp.CloseDate =  date.parse(startDate); 
    //newOpp.CloseDate = ESD_Date_Clone__c ;// Date.parse(esdDateString);      
    newOpp.Markets__c = pMarkets;   
    insert newOpp;
    system.debug('inserted opp=======>'+newOpp);
     PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/'+newOpp.Id);
    pageRef.setRedirect(true);
    return pageRef;

}
```

Comment: Hello @username, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. This just looks like a bunch of code, without a real question behind it, and is likely to be closed as a result.

Comment: Yes, please use *words* to explain what you are trying to achieve and clarify the behavior you observe. Do you get any error messages? If so please include them in your post *verbatim*. Also, please **[edit]** your post with any of these clarifications. Thanks!

Comment: Imagine trying to help someone resolve their error and they tell you *I am facing issue*. How can we possibly help you when you provide this level of detail? Please **[edit]** this post to include any error messages ***verbatim***. If you are not getting errors, please clarify the observed behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/one/one.app#/sObject/'+cloneOppId);
```

is not how you navigate in LEX from an apex visual force controller.

Use usual navigation from apex to navigate to the object detail page:

```
PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/'+cloneOppId);
```

Complete example:

**Visualforce Page**

```
<apex:page controller="myRedirectExample">

    <apex:form >
        <apex:commandButton action="{!gotoOpp}" value="Click Me"/>
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class myRedirectExample{



    public pagereference gotoOpp(){
        Opportunity o = [Select Id From Opportunity Limit 1];
        Pagereference pr = New Pagereference('/' + o.Id);
        return pr;

    }

}
```

**Then**

1. Create a button on an object like the Account (just to be different), detail page button, URL type, code `/apex/myRedirectExample`
2. Add button to object page layout in both the custom buttons and the Lightning actions

Try it out in classic.
Try it out in Lex.

If your current code is not working then you are doing something wrong and will need to debug it. You can use the above a a complete proof of life.

Comment: @AnnappaMoily - Then you are causing the issue elsewhere. You may even be throwing an error you do not see as you have no page messages on your page or you are not meeting the logic criteria to hit the page reference line. Break out the debugger and review whats going on. See above drop in example to prove it works as expected. You have not provided enough detail to help in any other way.

Comment: @AnnappaMoily - Seems like you need some fundamental education: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_dev_visualforce/units/lex_dev_visualforce_navigation - we can't play 20 questions here....Once you run through the trailhead I am sure you will have a better handle on it

Comment: ha ha...all the ways I tried.then i posted this question..i will look into it..thanks for link  :)

Comment: @AnnappaMoily - Interesting as the very first line of the trailhead is **The first rule for building Visualforce navigation in JavaScript is: do not set window.location**

Comment: Yes you are right.I checked that one...see opportunity is creating..if opportunity creates ill get the id but how the way u told me same way i told before but no result..tats y i told tat one tats it eric..no errors also :)

Comment: Huh? I can't debug your code here. You have not provided enough information. Did you even try the complete example *in isolation* to see that it does indeed work?

Comment: check my updated code snipet for opportunity creation..then tell me whats the wrong dere

Comment: @AnnappaMoily - Depends on how you are calling `CreateNewOpportunity();` if it is from the code you initially posted it, returning a Pagereference in that method will not do anything since the method was called from another method. You would have to do `return CreateNewOpportunity();` to return the page reference.